# How to show only first depth in cytoscape js?

Tags: cytoscape.js

Is it possible to show a root element and its neighbors only without going deeper? I need this because I want that user expands the tree by clicking on nodes, while initially, the user can see only the first level.

I'm going to use `cytoscape.js-view-utilities` plugin for showing/hiding elements.

I know that there is `neighborhood()` method, but cannot figure out how to do this

Answer (score 3):

As you said, you can do it by using view-utilities extension. First you should hide all nodes except the root and its neighbors. Then with a tap event on nodes, you can show neighbors of clicked node. In the below example, if you click on node n1 and n2, their neighbors are shown. If you want to differentiate nodes with hidden neighbors, you can assign them a new class and style, and define your tap event on that class.

```js
var cy = window.cy = cytoscape({
  container: document.getElementById('cy'),
  layout: {name: 'breadthfirst', directed: true},
  style: [{
      selector: 'node',
      css: {
        'label': 'data(id)'
      }
    }
  ],  
  elements: {
    nodes: [{
        data: {
          id: 'n0'          
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: 'n1'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: 'n2'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: 'n3'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: 'n4'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: 'n5'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: 'n6'
        }
      }      
    ],
    edges: [{
        data: {
          id: 'n0n1',
          source: 'n0',
          target: 'n1',
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: 'n0n2',        
          source: 'n0',
          target: 'n2'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: 'n1n3',        
          source: 'n1',
          target: 'n3'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: 'n1n4',        
          source: 'n1',
          target: 'n4'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: 'n2n5',        
          source: 'n2',
          target: 'n5'
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: 'n2n6',        
          source: 'n2',
          target: 'n6'
        }
      }
    ]
  }
});

var instance = cy.viewUtilities();

instance.hide(cy.elements().difference(cy.getElementById('n0').closedNeighborhood()));

cy.on('tap', 'node', function(event){
  instance.show(event.target.neighborhood());
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 14px helvetica neue, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}

#button {
  z-index = 1000;
}

#cy {
  height: 95%;
  width: 95%;
  left: 0;
  top: 50;
  z-index = 900;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimal-ui">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape/dist/cytoscape.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape-view-utilities/cytoscape-view-utilities.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="cy"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Woah, thank you so much! It's so elegant, I just didn't know that terminology, so closedNeighborhood told me nothing. Is it possible to toggle neighborhood elements on tap? Like, when I click on n1 it toggles neighborhood elements?